# On a single node, is there any reason I should choose MPI over other inter-process mechanisms?

Tags: c++, c, multiprocessing, mpi, hpc

Currently I am implementing a multi-processing application. Different processes seldom share data, instead each process will work on its own pre-divided chunk of data for most of the time. With that said, these processes are pretty independent, except occasionally they communicate for control or feedback purposes, and collecting results in the end.

So my question is, is there any reason I should choose MPI over other inter-process mechanisms? Or is there any reason preventing me from choosing MPI?

I am not sure if on a single node, MPI is efficient enough.

Comment: Very very broad. MPI can do some things, other things can do other things, and some things can be done with multiple tools. You need to be more specific.

Comment: But if there is not much communication the communication cost should not be too significant anyways.

Comment: @BaummitAugen So as long as the communication is not heavy, either MPI or other inter-process mechanisms makes no difference? And MPI is preferred only if much communication is required. Is this correct?

Comment: If communication rarely happens, it usually does not matter how fast it is done. If communication takes up a significant amount of time, you need to find out what mechanism is best for your specific problem, there is no blanket advice for that. But MPI is probably not bad.

Answer (score 2):

MPI is an interface that let you to communicate between multiple process. When your processes are not communicating together (with the MPI code) and not doing parallelized code, they are not more or less eficient than a standalone process.

MPI is made for high performance, scalability, and portability. Most of the time MPI is used for scientific computing because of it's caracteristics that I enumeratate. It helps scientifics to save time.

The communication interface include function like broadcast, scatter, gather, reduction that help to reduce time of processing. In other communication mechanisme (most of them) you need to think about the efficient part of your communication by yourself.

If you only need a simple communication with two process, and the processing time is not a concern, you should use the inter-process message passing mechanismes of your OS. Sometimes MPI become tricky and difficult if you don't follow the idea for what MPI is made. And if you are juste begining to that, I think it's better for your to begin with OS mechanisms.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To my understanding, MPI provides facilities to allow its processes (ranks) to cooperate with each other easily. E.g, each process can know its own process id (which rank it is), and total process number. Also, there is something like barrier to allow all processes to synchronize. Probably other message passing mechanisms (my OS is linux) are able to achieve the same thing, but probably requires more work from me?
Also, could you elaborate a little bit on " Sometimes MPI become tricky and difficult if you don't follow the idea for what MPI is made"? Thanks.

Comment: If you read enough about MPI and how to use function like gather or gatherv or other functions you see that it's easy to make mistakes when sending or interpreting informations communicated between processes. You can see the following link that show how to gather simple dimension array and two dimensional arrays. http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node70.html

Answer (score 1):

Captain Wise spoke to the efficiency aspect.  Consider the maintainability aspect as well.

If you use MPI and your code grows more complex and larger and some day needs to run on more than one node, then your porting and tuning effort might be as simple as "run on more than one node" -- presuming, of course, that your MPI implementation is clever enough to skip the networking stack when a message is  passed on the same node.

If you want to show your code to a future collaborator, its likely they will know MPI if you are at all affiliated with HPC environments, and your possible future collaborator can just dive in and help you.  The pool of Chapel or UPC users is a bit smaller (though if you use Chapel, Brad Chamberlain will work insanely hard to ensure you have a good experience)